# Generate an increment ID that is unique for a given value of a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are working on an ecommerce system where we aggregate orders coming in from different sellers. As you can easily imagine we have an `Order` table that holds the data for orders of all sellers. Each seller has a unique `AccountID` which is a foreign key in the `Order` table.

We want to generate an order number for each order that is coming into the system so that for a given seller (and given `AccountID`) those order numbers are creating a sequence (first order gets 1, then 2, then 3 etc).

We have tried a couple of solutions to this but they have drawbacks we would like to avoid. All of them are inside a trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Order_UpdateAccountOrderNumber] 
   ON [dbo].[Order]
   AFTER INSERT
BEGIN
     ...
END
```

Our *Solution 1* was:

```
UPDATE
    [Order]
SET
    AccountOrderNumber = o.AccountOrderNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT
        OrderID,
        AccountOrderNumber =
            ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 AccountOrderNumber FROM [Order] WHERE AccountID = i.AccountID ORDER BY AccountOrderNumber DESC), 1) +
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.AccountID ORDER BY i.OrderID))
    FROM
        inserted AS i
) AS o
WHERE [Order].OrderID = o.OrderID
```

Note that we have we have `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`. It seemed to work well for a while but recently we noticed some duplicate values in the `AccountOrderNumber` column. After analysing the code it seems logical that duplicates might appear as the operation is not atomic, so if 2 orders are added at the exact same time they will read the same `TOP 1` value from the `Order` table.

After noticing the duplicates we came up with *Solution 2* where we have a separate table to track the next `AccountOrderNumber` for each `Account`:

```
DECLARE @NewOrderNumbers TABLE
    (
        AccountID int, 
        OrderID int,
        AccountOrderNumber int
    }
```

The trigger body is a as follows in that case:

```
INSERT INTO @NewOrderNumbers (AccountID, OrderID, AccountOrderNumber)
    SELECT
        I.AccountID,
        I.OrderID,
        ASN.Number + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.AccountID ORDER BY I.OrderID))
    FROM
        inserted AS I
        INNER JOIN AccountSequenceNumber ASN WITH (UPDLOCK) ON I.AccountID = ASN.AccountID AND ASN.AccountSequenceNumberTypeID = @AccountOrderNumberTypeID


    UPDATE [Order] ...
```

While this solution did not create any duplicates it did cause deadlocks on the newly created `@NewOrderNumbers` table due to `WITH (UPDLOCK)`. Unfortunately, the locking was necessary to avoid duplicates.

Our latest attempt (*Solution 3*) is to use sequences. For this we need to create a sequence for each `Account` in our system and then use it when a new orders are inserted. Here is the code that creates a sequence for `AccountID = 1`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Seq_Order_AccountOrderNumber_1 AS INT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 100
```

And the trigger body for `AccountID = 1`:

```
    DECLARE @NumbersRangeToAllocate INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM inserted);

    DECLARE @range_first_value_output SQL_VARIANT; 
    EXEC sp_sequence_get_range N'Seq_Order_AccountOrderNumber_1', @range_size = @NumbersRangeToAllocate, @range_first_value = @range_first_value_output OUTPUT; 

    DECLARE @Number INT = CAST(@range_first_value_output AS INT) - 1;
    UPDATE 
        o
    SET 
        @Number = o.AccountOrderNumber = @Number + 1
    FROM 
        dbo.[Order] AS b JOIN inserted AS i on o.OrderID = i.OrderID
```

The approach with sequences worries us because we expect to have 100K+ accounts in the system pretty soon and for each of those accounts we currently need that sort of incremented ID in 6 different tables. This means we will end up with hundreds of thousands of sequences, which might have a negative impact on performance of the whole DB. We don't know if it will have any impact, but it is close to impossible to find any testimony on the web from people who have used that many sequences in SQL Server.

Finally, the question is: Can you think of a better solution to the problem? It seems like this should be a pretty common use case where you need an ID that is incremented separately for every value of a foreign key. Maybe we are missing something obvious here?

We will also welcome your comments on the 3 solutions detailed above. Maybe one of them is close to being acceptable and just needs some minor tweaking?

Comment: Why do you need to have order numbers be sequential for each customer? That makes no sense to me at all. Why not just an identity and let every single order have a unique value? Something seems very off with your design here.

Comment: Have you looked into the CREATE SEQUENCE object and NEXT VALUE FOR function?

Comment: @SeanLange is right. What's the problem to have unique IDs and create the ordered sequence using window functions when data is read?

Comment: I think solution 1 and 2 is good - you should fight with deadlocks.

Comment: Orders are never deleted? Transactions never roll back? Sequences may skip values after a restart. Will the universe end with a divide-by-zero if a seller notices that they have no order 42?

Comment: @HABO nope, we are fine with missing some elements in a sequence, but we are not fine with duplicates.

Comment: @SeanLange You would be surprised, but our users get really confused if the order numbers in their Accounts are not consecutive. Before introducing those increment IDs we had a lot of support requests asking if they are missing most of their orders, because there are gaps of literally hundreds of IDs between their orders.

Comment: @gotqn The order numbers need to be persisted for every order, so they cannot be generated on the fly, when reading data. This order number will be sent to the buyer and when the buyer calls in to ask about their order this is the reference they will give.

Comment: @JacobH Yes, we tried doing it with sequences in our 3rd solution, but instead of `NEXT VALUE FOR` we are using `sp_sequence_get_range`. The solution is working ok, but we are not sure it is scalable, as pointed out towards the end of my question.

Comment: The crazy part is needing a different set of incrementing values for each customer. That means you are going to have to use dynamic sql since every insert will be a different customer and therefore a different sequence. That approach is not going to be manageable in the long run.

Comment: I think it is a pretty common business requirement. Think of invoicing software - it is a legal requirement in some countries that each user of your system has consecutive invoice IDs. So it is not a question of whether this is a good idea, believe me if we could we would have resigned from this already.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably cleverer ways to achieve this but here is my quick proposal. Create a view that maintains the highest account order number; use schemabinding for speed and use the view to insert records.

View definition:

```
create view dbo.vwMaxAccountOrderNumber
with schemabinding as
select o.AccountID,
    max(o.AccountOrderNumber) as Sequence
from Orders as o
group by o.AccountID
```

Then use it for insert statements if you are `insert...selecting` like so:

```
insert into Orders (
    OrderID,
    AccountID,
    AccountOrderNumber,
    ...
    )
select SomeAutoIncrementValue,
       AccountID,
       vmaon.Sequence + row_number() (partition by a.AccountID order by SomeOtherColumn)
from Accounts as a
inner join dbo.vwMaxAccountOrderNumber as vmaon
on vmaon.AccountID = a.AccountID
inner join ...
```

Or like so for `insert...values`:

```
insert into Orders (
    OrderID,
    AccountID,
    AccountOrderNumber,
    ...
    )
values (
    SomeAutoIncrementValue,
    12,
    (select Sequence + 1 from dbo.vwMaxAccountOrderNumber where AccountID = 12),
    ...
    )
```

Comment: Will that avoid duplicates when two orders are inserted at the same time and they both read the same value from `dbo.vwMaxAccountOrderNumber` before any of them is inserted?

Comment: Not really but you are talking about deadlock prevention level simultaneity. If you wrap your inserts inside a transaction, it shouldn't affect you. I would test out the solution but like I said this a quick and not very clever solution.

Comment: I don't believe schema binding will make your view any faster ... unless you also index the view, then schema binding is required.

Comment: @JSR, that is excellent advice that I missed. An index should be created on the view for even better performance but... schema binding itself has performance advantages such as the lack of halloween protection which also helps with insert statements like the one OP is looking for. Here is more info: http://www.sqlhammer.com/sql-server-schemabinding/.

Comment: That's all nice, but I fail to see how this solution is any better than what we have initially (Solution 1 in my question). If I wrap the insert in a transaction will that make it atomic and allow us to avoid duplicates?

Comment: For one thing, you don't need triggers so there is that. Plus if you read the article I linked to, you will see how schema bound views manage read and write cursors (internal concept, not SQL construct) and how they help avoid eager reads. This is much better option for your kind of insert statements.